# evaluate $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(3y)}{2xy}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying calculus of multiple variables and I can solve limits of the form $x^2+y^2$, but I need to solve this.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(3y)}{2xy}$$

Could you give me an idea of how to solve that limit?

---

Comment: Write it as $\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin3y}{3y}\cdot\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: omg,, I did not see that, I've been forgetting of calculate 1,, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As was written in the comments, you could use the fact that limits are multiplicative to conclude
$$\begin{split}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin x \sin 3y}{2xy} &= \frac 1 2 \cdot \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin 3y}{y}
\\ &= \frac 3 2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin 3y}{3y}
\\ &= \frac 3 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac 3 2.
\end{split}$$
Alternatively, you could solve it directly by seeing that, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, we have the first-order expansion $\sin(x) \simeq x$ and $\sin 3y \simeq 3y$, so that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin x \sin 3y}{2xy} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{3xy}{2xy} = \frac 3 2. $$

Answer (score 0):

As written, the quotient isn't defined if $x = 0$ or $y  = 0$. Excluding this subset, you can use that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t} = 1$.